# Flash Pro CS6 Unable to transcode assets?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I was testing my project in CS6. Everything was fine. I literally changed nothing. I test. Tons of errors that it is unable to transcode embedded movieClips. I am literally going insane trying to find out why this is happening.. the errors:

/Volumes/FLASHDRIVE/CodeCanyon/Example/src/mvc/View.as, Line 140    Unable to transcode /Volumes/FLASHDRIVE/CodeCanyon/Example/src/mvc/assets/graphic.swf.

/Volumes/FLASHDRIVE/CodeCanyon/Example/src/mvc/View.as, Line 144    definition for symbol 'VContent22' not found

52 errors all like this. Obviously, these movieclips do exist in the exact file that is specified here. Does anyone know what could be going on here??

Here is the code:

[Embed (source = "/Volumes/FLASHDRIVE/CodeCanyon/Example/src/mvc/assets/graphic.swf", symbol = "VContent1")]
        private var VContent1:Class;

Comment: Have you verified the path of graphic.swf ? Do all of the filename paths begin with the '/' ?

Comment: Sometimes you'll get errors like these as a result of a problem in an unrelated part of the code. Considering that you already have these assets in a fla or xfl somewhere, you may want to try making a swc. This should allow the true error to surface.

Comment: @ proto - yes, . I put the code above. @ Amy - I just made a swc and added it to the main file. Exact same errors. what does this mean? ?